# Use welcomepage from parent on subsites

Tags: master-page, page-layout, custom-masterpage

How can I use a custom welcomepage (Home.aspx) on every subsite I create?
When I select the Welcomepage in Site Settings I get an Welcome page invalid error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Morten,

Mostly the navigation, left/top and content on MasterPage are the things you want remain same on the sub-sites as well.. But the content of the homepage should differ from that of parent site, it should show the details related to your sub-site!

So if you want your parent site MasterPage to be used by your sub-sites as well, you can turn on the Publishing Infrastructure Feature [Turn on from Site Collection Features and then Site Features]..

After turning on this feature -> In Site Settings -> Under Look and Feel -> **Master Page** : This will give you an option to use the same MasterPage from parent site for your sub-sites, below is an image:
[image: MasterPage Settings]

You need to check **Reset all subsites to inherit this master page setting**

I hope this helps

Comment: Arh.. I can't do that, because as you said, the content needs to differ. Thanks!